# I Dont see AKS from DevOps - Service Connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

Im not seeing AKS from DevOps. Im trying to create a pipeline but AKS is not showing.

First of all, I created a service connection --> Azure Resource Manager --> Service Principal (Manual)

I have been working this way and I see all my AKS. I have a problem with this new one.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHpyq.png)

I dont know where is the problem. In DevOps I can see all my AKS except this new one

Any ideas to check?

Comment: Does the service principal you're using have access to the AKS resource in question?

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: service principal has contributor access

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure DevOps project navigate to Project Settings > Service Connections and select your Service Connection to Azure which will look something like this:

[image: AzureDevOpsServiceConnection]

Depending on how your Service Principal was set up you may be able to browse to it directly in the Azure Portal by clicking the `Manage Service Principal` link.  There are other ways to set up a Service Connection and the method to find the Service Principal in the Azure Portal will differ, checkout the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops).  Make a note of the Display Name for your Service Principal.

In the Azure Portal navigate to your AKS resource then navigate to the Access Control (IAM) blade and click Role Assignments.  Check what Roles the Azure AD Service Principal for your Azure DevOps Service Connection has been assigned, it will need at least Contributor to make changes to your AKS cluster.

Comment: yes, Service principal has contributor access on AKS. Any other idea?

Comment: as you can't see any Resource Groups either it may be a permissions issue at the subscription or resource group level.  What permissions does your Service Principal have there?

Comment: If I give contributor access in the subscription, I can see all my AKS but not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `verify` connection link on the Edit service connection page to verify your connection information and check whether the `Grant access permission to all pipelines` option is checked.

[image]

In addition,here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops) on Troubleshoot Azure Resource Manager service connections you can refer to.

Comment: yes, Grant access permission to all pipelines option is checked. Any other idea?